# Folder structure to deploy app on EC2 instance

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, package, web-deployment

I am setting up a new React app on EC2 instance (ubuntu). I have installed nodeJS and npm and I am able to build my app successfully. 
Issue is my code is in /var/www/html folder and my site example.com is pointed to this folder.

when I run

```
npm run build
```

It builds a folder under /html like /html/build now my app runs on example.com/build. Resources for these files comes from example.com/static/style.css etc but they actually reside under example.com/build/static

I can edit asset-manifest.json and change the path but thats not appropriate solution as I need to get rid of /build folder for production

Answer (score 0):

I am not super familiar with deployments to EC2 but this looks like you just need to either copy the entire contents of your app inside `var/www/html`, or you need to tell `apache` or `nginx` to look to the right folder (in this case `/build`)

For example, with apache you probably have a file inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` that is pointing to `/var/www/html`, you could change that to `/var/www/html/build` and restart apache.

You can check this for examples on how to write these configurations https://gist.github.com/rambabusaravanan/578df6d2486a32c3e7dc50a4201adca4

Comment: I tried it and changed apache2.conf file Documentroot but then I see Forbidden when I go to example.com

Comment: Probably you need to adjust the ownership of the folder so apache can read it like: `sudo chown -R www-data:www:data "your dir"`
But this is a long shot, maybe you could share your virtualhost conf. Also, you probably have a file called `000-default.conf` inside `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, you can modify the virtualhost there and then run `sudo a2dissite 000-default` and then `sudo a2ensite 000-default`. Then restart apache and it should work